# I want to start to use C++ inline initialization, is there any bad cases for it?

Tags: c++, c++11

If i have a `struct` like this:

```
struct A 
{
    int i;
    double d;
    const bool b;
};
```

And I do this: `A a;` then I get non-value initialized object, i.e. `i` can be `6`, `d` can be some other thing `b` can be `true`. So for avoiding this I want to do the following:

```
struct A 
{
    int i = 0;
    double d = 0.0;
    const bool b = false;
};
```

Is there something bad to use this approach as a rule of thumb? Maybe you know a case, when this is not desirable to do?

Comment: I think making default constructor for struct is look more relevant .
`struct A 
{
    int i;
    double d;
    const bool b;
   A()
   {  i =0;
      d = 0.0;
      b = false;
   }
};`

Comment: It's not the problem here, but you should order the member declarations by size

Comment: @vidhugangwar: The constructor makes the struct ***non-POD*** which may be undesirable in some use cases.

Comment: @vidhugangwar: And your solution doesn't compile (as ``b` is const)... and make the struct non aggregate for anyway. The OP way is concise and correct.

Comment: @Jarod42  `struct A { int i; double d; const bool b; A() :b(false){ i =0; d = 0.0; } };`

this solution is compiled .

Comment: @vidhugangwar: If you're going to use an initializer list, why aren't you using it for all members? This is inconsistent.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
struct A 
{
    int i = 0;
    double d = 0.0;
    const bool b = false;
};
```

is correct and concise.

Comment: In C++11 `A() = default;` still keeps `A` an aggregate type.

Comment: @Narek: `A() = default`; wouldn't (zero-) initialize the members.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by using initialization list in constructor.

```
struct A 
{
    int i;
    double d;
    const bool b;

    A(int i, double d, bool b) : i(i), d(d), b(b){}
};
```